# Short PHP/MYSQL code to get data from table?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new in PHP/Mysql and I do many search but could not find the answer to my question.

I have a Mysql table :

```
Table1

Name        Age
-------- ----------

tim         21
scott       25
jenny       30
adrian      31
suzane      22
albert      29
kim         33
wiliam      36
diana       23
```

### What I'd Like To Do

I would like use PHP to list 3 Names with theire Ages like this :

```
The winners are : jenny==30 ; kim==33 ; diana==23 ;
```

### What I've tried

```
$sql_jenny = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE name LIKE 'jenny'");
$req_jenny = mysql_fetch_array($sql_jenny);
$row_jenny = $req_jenny[2] ;

$sql_kim = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE name LIKE 'kim'");
$req_kim = mysql_fetch_array($sql_kim);
$row_kim = $req_kim[2] ;

$sql_diana = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE name LIKE 'diana'");
$req_diana = mysql_fetch_array($sql_diana);
$row_diana = $req_diana[2] ;

echo 'The winners are :';
echo 'jenny == '.$row_jenny;
echo 'kim == '.$row_kim;
echo 'diana == '.$row_diana;
```

### My question is

What I tried is working fine but Because once a month I would need to modify the list of winners displayed in my website and I'm going to edit my php file once a month I'm looking for a way to have a script with  three variables at the beginning of the script to indicate the names of the winners in order to avoid edit multiple lines for each winner and every month

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look here - http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-and-MySQL.html

Comment: Why is what you tried not working? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Do you want 3 random names?

Comment: What I tried is working but while I will need to change the winners once every mounth or less I'm looking for someting short because sometimes I will need to list more than 3 winners, I'm looking for a script maybe with variables that I could change in the beginning of the php file instead of changing the whole code.

Comment: You really need to look into basic PHP and MySQL again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? (untested)

```
$names = array('jenny', 'kim', 'diana');
$data = array();

foreach ($names as $item) {
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE name LIKE '$item'");
    $req = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    array_push($data, $req[2]);
}

echo "The winners are : ";

foreach ($names as $key => $value) {
    echo "$names[$key] == $data[$key]";
}
```

Comment: Yep, you got it, this what I was looking for, I don't test it yet but you give a good idea and I will work on it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to purely use SQL then how about the following ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e16c6/13/0)):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.name, '==', t.age SEPARATOR '; ')
FROM Table1 AS t
WHERE t.name = 'tim'
OR t.name = 'scott'
OR t.name = 'albert'
```

Which will produce the following result:

```
tim==21; scott==25; albert==29
```

Or if you want it to ***randomly grab 3 names*** then do the following ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ac9e/5/0)):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(mq.name, '==', mq.age SEPARATOR '; ')
FROM 
(
  SELECT * FROM Table1 
  WHERE id >= 
    (
      SELECT FLOOR(MAX(id) * RAND()) 
      FROM Table1
    ) 
  ORDER BY id LIMIT 3
) AS mq;
```

In this example if you run the SQL you will get different results each time.  The advantage of using this query is you can change the quantity of names returned simply by changing the `LIMIT 3` to what ever you need.  You could also use a variable for the number.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th></tr>
<?php

/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = 'localhost';

/*** mysql username ***/
$username = 'username';

/*** mysql password ***/
$password = 'password';

/*** mysql database name ***/
$dbname = 'periodic_table';

/*** create a new mysqli object with default database***/
$mysqli = @new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);

/* check connection */ 
if(!mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    /*** if we are successful ***/
    echo 'Connected Successfully<br />';

    /*** our SELECT query ***/
    $sql = "SELECT name, age FROM table1 ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT=3";

    /*** prepare statement ***/
    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql))
        {
        /*** execute our SQL query ***/
        $stmt->execute();
        /*** bind the results ***/
        $stmt->bind_result($name, $age);
        /*** loop over the result set ***/
        while ($stmt->fetch())
            {
            /*** echo our table rows ***/
            echo '<tr><td>'.$name.'</td><td>'.$age.'</td></tr>';
            }
        }
    /*** close connection ***/
    $mysqli->close();
    }
else
    {
    /*** if we are unable to connect ***/
    echo 'Unable to connect';
    exit();
    }
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you tried seems decent...
What error(s) do you get? are you connect to the database?
If you are connected to the database already (code not shown)

Maybe you need to try this:

Change

```
$row_jenny = $req_jenny[2] ;
```

to

```
$row_jenny = $req_jenny[1] ;
```

PHP arrays start at 0 and age is probably element 1 of the array. Good luck!

Comment: I'm connected to the databaseand What I tried is working correctly,  but beacause I will need to change the winners once every mounth or less, I'm looking for someting short because sometimes I will need to list more than 3 winners, I'm looking for a script maybe with variables that I could change in the beginning of the php file instead of changing the whole code. Thanks

Comment: You should then just turn all your "queries" into variables. For example, replace Jenny and Kim with $winner[0], $winner[1].
Then you can "initialize the $winner array at the start of the file and only change that.

Turn your querying into a for loop that goes through each element of $winner array. And this will make it scalable for any # of winners.